# Completely Disable onKeyDown/onKeyUp events in FireFox

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 34.0.5.  I am sick and tired of websites defining their own key bindings that override the defaults in FireFox - its a craps shoot as to if a particular key binding will work or not.  For example, Ctrl+0 on YouTube no longer resets the zoom in FireFox... it restarts the video.  I cannot tell you how many sites that / no longer is bound to firefox's quick search.

Websites defining their own key bindings are a plague.

I can find no setting to disable these events in firefox.  Is there such a setting?  is there an extension that will allow me to rid myself of this?